# Merge two maps in java when first map has key or value as null

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I am trying to merge 2 maps but only when either key is missing or value for a certain key is null in the first map then only override from the second.

Following is the sample method where I get `Map` from 2 `findFirst` operations.
Can I simplify the below code using java 8 and avoid many loops?

So sample o/p is as :

```
map1 = {A=1,B=null}
map2 = {A=2,B=3,C=5}

//Merged Map
map3 = {A=1,B=3,C=5}
```

Following is the method if hat can also be simplified :

```
private Map<String, Object> getMergedMap(String key, Object value, List<Map<String, Object>> dataList1, List<Map<String, Object>> dataList2) {

    Map<String, Object> map1 = dataList1.parallelStream()
                    .filter(dataMap -> value != null && value.equals(dataMap.get(key)))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(Collections.emptyMap());

    Map<String, Object> map2 = dataList2.parallelStream()
                    .filter(dataMap -> value != null && value.equals(dataMap.get(key)))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(Collections.emptyMap());


    //Merge here                
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may plainly add all the missing keys/values from the second map:

```
private Map<String, Object> getMergedMap(String key, Object value, List<Map<String, Object>> dataList1, List<Map<String, Object>> dataList2) {

    Map<String, Object> map1 = dataList1.parallelStream()
                    .filter(dataMap -> value != null && value.equals(dataMap.get(key)))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(Collections.emptyMap());

    Map<String, Object> map2 = dataList2.parallelStream()
                    .filter(dataMap -> value != null && value.equals(dataMap.get(key)))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(Collections.emptyMap());

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map2.entrySet()) {
        if (map1.get(entry.getKey()) == null) {
            map1.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    return map1;
}
```

Or, using Java8 cumbersome construct instead of the loop:

```
    map2.entrySet().stream()
            .filter((entry) -> (res.get(entry.getKey()) == null))
            .forEachOrdered((entry) -> {
        map1.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    });
```

Comment: Looks elegant and simple solution!!

Comment: @JavaBuilder you may choose it as the correct one if you like it

Answer (score 0):

This does it by simply mapping the appropriate values based on a ternary condition and creating a new map.

```
Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>(Map.of("A", 1));
map1.put("B", null);
Map<String, Integer> map2 =
        new HashMap<>(Map.of("A", 2, "B", 3, "C", 5));
```

Now stream the map2 entryset, replacing as needed.

```
Map<String, Integer> map3 = map2.entrySet().stream()
                .map(e2 -> map1.containsKey(e2.getKey())
                        && map1.get(e2.getKey()) == null
                        || !map1.containsKey(e2.getKey()) ?
                                Map.entry(e2.getKey(),
                                        map2.get(e2.getKey())) :
                                Map.entry(e2.getKey(),
                                        map1.get(e2.getKey())))

                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                        Entry::getValue));
```

Prints

```
{A=1, B=3, C=5}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is doing like: since the null value exists in the `map1` I used  `map2.getOrDefault(k, map1.get(k))` and for absents key in the map2 I used `map1.get(k)`. for duplicate keys always `map2`'s values will chose.

```
Stream.concat(map1.keySet().stream(), map2.keySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                          k->map2.getOrDefault(k, map1.get(k)),(l, r) -> l));
```

however for better performance you can compute the keys at first:

```
Set<String> keys = Stream.concat(map1.keySet().stream(), map2.keySet().stream())
                          .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

and then:

```
keys.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),k->map2.getOrDefault(k, map1.get(k))));
```

---

I think maybe you can do it without creating `map1` and `map2` and just by working on `dataList1` and `dataList2`

Answer (score 0):

It needs to iterate second map and compare with the the other one.

```
    Map<String, Integer> map3 = new HashMap<>(map1);
    map2
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter((k) -> !map3.containsKey(k.getKey()) || map3.get(k.getKey()) == null)
        .forEach(k -> map3.put(k.getKey(), k.getValue()));

    System.out.println("map1 : " + map1);
    System.out.println("map2 : " + map2);
    System.out.println("map3 : " + map3);
```

output

```
map1 : {A=1, B=null}
map2 : {A=2, B=3, C=5}
map3 : {A=1, B=3, C=5}
```